# Changing multiple elements with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-manipulation

I'm not familiar with JQuery at all, but I was wondering if it's possible to change all elements with the same id on actions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("id_scheduled_time").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("id_scheduled_day").disabled = true;
});

$('#id_schedule_type').on('change', function() {
    if ($("#id_schedule_type").prop('selectedIndex') == 0) {
        document.getElementById("id_scheduled_time").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("id_scheduled_day").disabled = true;

    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("id_scheduled_time").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("id_scheduled_day").disabled = false;
    };
});


$('#id_scheduled_period').on('change', function() {
    if ($("#id_scheduled_period").prop('selectedIndex') == 2) {
        $('#id_scheduled_minute').attr("placeholder","Insert number 1-15").val("");
    } else {
        $('#id_scheduled_minute').attr("placeholder","Insert number 1-45").val("");
    };
});
```

Yes, this code looks like shit but does it work for now. The problem for me is that there are multiple tabs with selection boxes and input fields which all have the same id (for example `id_scheduled_time`)

Now what it does it that it works fine in one single tab, but does nothing for the other id's.
The question here is: how do I change all the elements the same way for the selection indices

Comment: Your question is moot as `id` attributes *must* be unique within a document. If you want to group elements, use a class.

Comment: you must use a class instead of id , id must be unique.

Comment: You might want to use elements with the same `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: Yeah okay @RoryMcCrossan, I'm not familiar with this. I saw `id='id_scheduled_time'` were all the same so I was wondering why It was working for the first tab then and not for the others

Comment: if your parent tabs have same class name then you can bind change event on that class name and do `$(this).find('#id_scheduled_time')`. but ideally you should not have duplicate ids

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of selecting the element with `$('#my-id')`, you could use `$('[id="my-id"]')` to select all of them.

However, as all the comments mention you should really switch to classes. ID's are not meant to be used more than once on a page.

Answer (score -1):

If you can not add class to this elements but target elements have parent with an exact class I suggest this:

```
$(".parentClassName:nth-child(3)")  
// The number 3 is a sample index of element inside its parent
```

or in an ugly way you can get all of those elements by:

```
$('[id="id_scheduled_time"]')
```